# To what height does the ball rebound and what is the velocity of the struck block after impact?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Here is the problem. I have tried it four different times, and I will show my most recent work.]

Here is the problem. I have tried it four different times, and I will show my most recent work.

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Hi Darian and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Yes sir. I apologize @JohnRennie

Answer (score 1):

1. As the ball swings downward, its gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. At the bottom of the swing, its velocity will all be in the horizontal direction. From this, you can calculate the velocity with which the ball strikes the block.
2. In a perfectly elastic collision, both kinetic energy and momentum are conserved. From this you can calculate the velocity of the block (in the +x direction) and the ball (in the -x direction) after the collision.
3. As the ball swings upward, its kinetic energy is converted to g.p.e. From this you can calculate how far back upward it swings.

Comment: Thank you, I started to use conservation of momentum due to the conserved momentum in the X-direction. Thank you!

Comment: One more question. In part 2 of your solution, how would I determine how fast the block is moving? Initial Momentum = Final Momentum or Initial Energy = Final Energy. Will the velocity of the ball's rebound be the negative of its original velocity? @The Photon

Comment: You have two unknowns: velocity of the ball, and velocity of the block. You have two equations: Initial momentum = Final momentum, and Initial k.e. = Final k.e. So you have to solve the two equations together to determine the two unknowns.

Comment: If you do not mind, I have one more inquiry. When the ball comes into contact with the block, the mass would be (m + 2m), so when I use Cons of Energy and Momentum, the initial should have mass (m + 2m), correct? @The Photon

Comment: @DarianNwankwo, you should consider the ball and the block as separate objects. The sum of their momemta and of their k.e. will be equal before and after the collision